# Looping over filenames in python

Tags: python

I have a zillion files in a directory I want a script to run on. They all have a filename like: prefix_foo_123456_asdf_asdfasdf.csv. I know how to loop over files in a directory using a variable in the filename in shell but not python. Is there a corresponding way to do something like

```
$i=0

for $i<100

./process.py prefix_foo_$i_*

$i++

endloop
```

Comment: @Levon (Your link goes back to this page, by the way.)

Comment: You can also [ask the Googles](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+loop+over+files).  There are a zillion answers or so ;)  The first one is `glob`, as noted by @mgilson.

Comment: @vergenzt Ooops .. thanks for catching that .. so silly .. I fixed it!

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry I didn't notice that earlier, I'm still new :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the standard library glob. Assuming the functionality of process.py is in the function process_one_file:

```
from glob import glob
from process import process_one_file

for i in range(100):
    process_one_file(glob('prefix_foo_{}_*'.format(i)))
```

Comment: +1 for importing the important stuff and not spawning a subprocess :)

Answer (score 4):

you can use `glob.glob` or `glob.iglob` to get a list/iterator of filenames.

e.g. if your directory has "file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt"

```
import glob
print (glob.glob('*.txt'))  #['file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt']
```

Although the list won't necessarily be sorted.

Your loop can be written as:

```
import subprocess
import glob
for i in range(100):
    files=glob.glob('prefix_foo_%d_*'%(i))
    subprocess.call(['./process.py']+files)
```

Of course, using subprocess in python to run another python program is probably not the best design...(you could probably import the stuff you need from the other module and run it without spawning another process)

Answer (score 2):

another way:

```
from os import walk

>>> for filename, subdirs, dirs in walk('/home'):
...     print (filename, subdirs, dirs)
```

output:

> home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/info [] ['exclude']
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/logs ['refs']
>   ['HEAD'] /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/logs/refs
>   ['remotes', 'heads'] []
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/logs/refs/remotes
>   ['origin'] []
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin
>   [] ['HEAD']
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/logs/refs/heads []
>   ['master'] /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/objects
>   ['info', 'pack'] []
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/objects/info [] []
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/objects/pack []
>   ['pack-a378eaa927a4825f049faf10bab35cf5d94545f1.idx',
>   'pack-a378eaa927a4825f049faf10bab35cf5d94545f1.pack']
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/refs ['tags',
>   'remotes', 'heads'] []
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/refs/tags [] []
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/refs/remotes
>   ['origin'] []
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/refs/remotes/origin
>   [] ['HEAD']
>   /home/di/workspace/local2stream/mediaelement/.git/refs/heads []
>   ['master']